# A piece of code is telling me "The Expression is unused"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm very new to App development. I'm stuck on a piece of code that's telling me "The Expression is unused".

The App itself is written in Kotlin, it's meant to be a conversion app. I'm pretty sure I got the math right, since 1 foot comes out to 30.48cm, which is correct. But, whenever I write a number (in the app) greater than 1 foot, it still always comes to 30.48cm. An example being if I were to type 5foot 9 in the app, the answer would still be 30.48cm. Here is the two blocks of code I'm pretty sure one of them is the culprit.

The first one.

'calculateHeight' is the line thats giving me "The Expression is unused"

```kotlin
private fun calculateButton() {

        val feetString: String = binding.editTextFeet.text.toString()
        val inchesString: String = binding.editTextInches.text.toString()
        val calculateHeight = calculateHeight()

        if (feetString.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please select a foot value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            calculateHeight
            displayText()
        }
        if (inchesString.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please select a inch value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            calculateHeight
            displayText()
        }

}
```

And the second one.

```kotlin
private fun calculateHeight(): Double {


        val feetHint = binding.editTextFeet.toString()
        val inchesHint = binding.editTextInches.toString()

        var feet = 1
        try {
            feet = feetHint.toInt()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        var inches = 0f
        try {
            inches = inchesHint.toInt().toFloat()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val totalFeet = feet * 12
        val totalInches = inches + 1f
        val heightInCentimeters = 2.54

        return ((totalFeet * totalInches) * heightInCentimeters)

    }

}
```

### Edit

This is the displayText():

```
private fun displayText() {

    val dec = DecimalFormat(".##")
    val resultString: String = dec.format(calculateHeight())
    binding.textViewCm.text = "$resultString - Centimeters"

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass the result of calculateHeight() into displayText()?  Writing `calculateHeight` on it's own line doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
        val calculateHeight = calculateHeight()
```

This line is calling the `calculateHeight()` function. That function reads the contents of your fields at that moment in time and performs calculations upon their contents. The result of the `calculateHeight()` function is then stored in the variable, itself confusingly named `calculateHeight`.

You then do not do anything meaningful with `calculateHeight`. You reference that variable twice, in statements that then do not do anything:

```kotlin
            calculateHeight
```

Those lines will give you "expression is unused", because the expression (`calculateHeight`) is unused. You are not doing anything with it.

> it still always comes to 30.48cm

You do not state where and how you are seeing any results. If I had to guess, `displayText()` is supposed to something like that, given the name of that function. Your question does not include the source for `displayText()`, so we are having to guess.

But, it is unclear where `displayText()` is getting anything to display. You are not passing any parameters to `displayText()`. Perhaps you should have `displayText(calculateHeight)`, and have your `displayText()` function take that parameter and do something with it. Or, perhaps `displayText()` should be calling `calculateHeight()` directly, and you can remove all the `calculateHeight()`/`calculateHeight` stuff from your `calculateButton()` function.